# Kafka ObjectDeserializer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to create a KafkaConsumer for a topic, simply for the purposes of using the offsetsForTimes() method. I actually don't wish to use it for consuming.

The topic in question has String keys and an Avro type has a value. Within my development environment, I am unable to include the generated Avro types, so, even though I can specify

```
consumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer")
```

for the consumer properties, I can't actually instantiate the parameterized instance

```
KafkaConsumer<String, [GeneratedAvroType]>
```

Fortunately, I won't be consuming, so maybe just

```
KafkaConsumer<String, Object>
```

would be acceptable? In this case I don't want to specify the deserializer in the properties as KafkaAvroDeserializer. Is there a simple ObjectDeserializer, or alternative deserializer that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you truly dont care about the payloads just go for a `Consumer<String, byte[]>`, and save yourself the CPU cycles of even trying to decode avro.

you do this by setting your `value.deserializer` for the consumer to be `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer` (which is included in the open source kafka-clients jar)

Comment: Once my code was cleaned and debugged, using KafkaAvroDeserializer in the properties and Object in the instantiation worked fine. I like the idea of using byte[], thanks. But even if using byte, what value for the value deserializer property would be appropriate? AvroDeserializer at least informs the reader what is in the stream, but I feel like this would give the impression that the consumer actually cared. What default value for the deserializer would you use in the Object of byte[] case?

Comment: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

its included in the open source kafka-clients jar and is the "cheapest" deserializer you could use